# How to pass array element by reference in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I want to multiply all my array element with 5,but my code give output 55555.Output should be 5 10 15 20 25.How to handle this?

```
<?php

    function multi($ar,$multiplier){
        $i=0;
        while($i<count($ar)){
            $ar[$i]*=$multiplier;
            echo $ar[0];
            $i++;
            }       
        }
    $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    multi($arr,5);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this will output what you want. It is also stored in another array called `outarr`, you can use that further.

```
<?php 
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$outarr = [];
foreach($arr as $piece){
    $output = $piece * 5;
    array_push($outarr,$output);
    echo $output."<br>";
}
?>
```

In case you want it function whise:

```
<?php 
function multi($array,$times = 5){
    foreach($array as $piece){
        $output = $piece * $times;
        array_push($outarr,$output);
        //echo $output."<br>";
    }
    return $outarr;
}

$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
multi($array);
var_dump(multi($array));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function multi($ar,$multiplier){
    $i=0;
    while($i<count($ar)){
        $ar[$i]*=$multiplier;
        echo $ar[$i];
        $i++;
        }       
    }
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
multi($arr,5);
```

Comment: So array automatically pass it's element by reference to any function?

Answer (score 0):

use & to trans parameters by reference,
see the [demo](https://eval.in/687311)

```
<?php

function multi(&$ar,$multiplier){
    $i=0;
    while($i<count($ar)){
        $ar[$i]*=$multiplier;
        //echo $ar[0];
        $i++;
    }       
}

$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
multi($arr,5);
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative would be to use simple `array_map()` for that. The Snippet below shows you how and you may [Quick-Test it Here](https://eval.in/687319).

```
    <?php

        // SAY YOU HAVE AN ARRAY: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
        // AND YOU WISH TO HAVE: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
        // YOU COULD SIMPLY USE array_map() TO DO JUST THAT...      
        $arrNumbers     = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);     
        $arrResult      = array_map( function($value){
            return 5*$value;
        }, $arrNumbers);

        var_dump($arrResult);
        // YIELDS::
        array (size=5)
          0 => int 5
          1 => int 10
          2 => int 15
          3 => int 20
          4 => int 25
```